# why array length in JavaScript does not change after adding property?

Tags: javascript, arrays

why does `myArray.length` is `3` here? I have added a new property in it, to my guess, it should be `4`.

```
    var myArray = [ "foo", 42, "bar" ];
    
    myArray.baz = "baz";
    
    myArray.length; // 3
```

Comment: you're adding a property to the myArray object - this is valid, but doesn't change the length of the array (unless the property was numeric, of course), to add to the "list" use a numeric index or push or unshift array methods - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: my question is why the length is not changed? technically I have 4 items in the array.

Comment: no you don't. `myArray` now has 4 properties: `0`, `1`, `2`, and `baz`.

Comment: my answer tells you why ... an array has the property called `length` and the property called `map`, and `find`, and `reduce` .... many many properties, but these are not included in `length` either ... the Array "length" property (I linked to some useful documentation you can read) is not a count of properties, it is always numerically greater than the highest index in the array. index being a NUMBER - and that number is `2`, therefore index is (at least) 3, because there are entries at 0, 1 and 2 only

Comment: If you want to add a new Item in array you can use myArray[3] = "baz", it's not an object, to do like that myArray.baz

Comment: from reading the documentation I get it. Arrays cannot use strings as element indexes (as in an associative array) but must use integers. Setting or accessing via non-integers using bracket notation (or dot notation) will not set or retrieve an element from the array list itself, but will set or access a variable associated with that array's object property collection. The array's object properties and list of array elements are separate, and the array's traversal and mutation operations cannot be applied to these named properties. thanks @Bravo

Comment: @Md.RajuAhmed - no, they CAN, an Array is an Object ... the only difference is that `length` is unaffected by non-numeric properties, and the array methods I mentioned before will not iterate over those non-numeric properties ... but it's perfectly OK (not advisable) to add properties to an array

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [Array.prototype.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) to add new elements to array. In your code `myArray.baz = "baz"` doesn't do anything.

```js
var myArray = [ "foo", 42, "bar" ];

// your approch
myArray.baz = "baz"; 

console.log(myArray.length); // 3
console.log(myArray) // [ "foo", 42, "bar" ]


// correct 
myArray.push("baz")

console.log(myArray.length); // 4
console.log(myArray) // [ "foo", 42, "bar", "baz" ]
```

Comment: or `unshift`, or `splice`, or `myArray[3] = 'baz'` ... have I missed any?

Comment: `myArray.baz = 'baz'` certainly DOES do something. It adds the property `baz` with the value `baz` to `myArray`

Comment: I know the correct approach, But I needed to know why.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. In the first line, you create a variable `myArray` and you add a value to it. Every variable in Javascript is an object, that has keys and properties (see more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)

> Between [] you create an array type, that stores data and labels them with numbers. (see more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

> 2. In the second line, you add a `baz` property to `myArray` with `"baz"` value

> 3. In the third line, you get the length property of the array

> If you want to add a(n) `"baz"` element to the end of the array, you can use the `.push()` method. For example: `myArray.push("baz");`

[image]

Comment: yes, good old `.push` always gets a mention, but what about `.unshift`, or `.splice`, or `myArray[3] = 'baz'` - why are they ignored options?

Comment: I needed to know why array length does not change adding named property to it.

Comment: @Bravo that's why I add links, to learn more about this topic. I saw the problem of the question is adding elements to the array, and the simplest method is the `.push()`.

Comment: Sure, but push gets all the love :p I wasn't criticizing :p

Comment: @Md.RajuAhmed because the `length` property is counting how many elements are in the array, not how many js object properties have it. In other languages, you can not add plus property to an array. Js is a high abstraction language, therefore you can do this strange thing.